# DNSmasq error: Too few arguments

Tags: dns

When I check the status of DNSmasq I get a "Too few arguments" error.

> Dec 12 11:05:18 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3593]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: started, version 2.80 cachesize 1000
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: DNS service limited to local subnets
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHC
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: warning: ignoring resolv-file flag because no-resolv is set
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: using nameserver 212.23.6.100#53
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: using nameserver 212.23.3.100#53
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3601]: read /etc/hosts - 56 addresses
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 dnsmasq[3602]: **Too few arguments.**
>   Dec 12 11:05:19 Indigo101 systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.

I have checked the hosts file and cannot see any errors.

What does this refer to and how do I fix it?

Comment: And what is your dnsmasq.conf file content ?

Comment: domain-needed, bogus-priv, no-resolve, server=212.23.3.100, server=212.23.6.100, cache-size=1000

Comment: have you try : `sudo killall dnsmasq` before running dnsmasq ? Else, use `interface=YOUR_INTERFACE` parameter for force dnsmasq to run dns server on specific interface only.

Comment: That wasn;t it, I've run out of time, I'll be back tomorrow. Thanks for your help

Comment: Add more option to the dnsmasq.conf file. If you don't know the structure, google it. There is plenty of examples on the internet.

Comment: I don't understand "more option". I have 6 entries in the conf file (see above).What else do I need?

Comment: If I delete the conf file in /etc/dnsmasq.d/ and enter the options into dnsmasq.conf the "Too few arguments" error goes away. Why?

Comment: I get this error with *no* files in /etc/dnsmasq.d/. This on an RPi with a  newly-installed debian "buster". If I figure it out, I'll be back.

Comment: It has to do with `/etc/hosts` and is not a problem in itself.